# Will downvoting affect an user who does not have enough reputation

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Suppose if a user asks a question with a reputation of 1 and his question is downvoted(more than his reputation. say for eg here downvote is 2) for some reasons but he is not having enough reputation to get it reduced. In that case when Reputation for downvote will get reduced? is there any time limit to get it decreased?

Comment: Will it affect him? Certainly, it will make him sad.

Comment: You have 1 reputation on Meta. Someone has downvoted you on this question. Did it affect you?

Comment: I know the rule is "an" for nouns beginning with a vowel but it really is "a user" not "an user". As for why? Search me

Comment: @hims056 Perhaps Downvoting this question shows the answer practically

Comment: And now upvoted, see your [reputation history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/235168/mogana?tab=reputation&sort=time) see how its as if the downvote never happened and the upvote gives you rep as normal

Comment: @gnat I much prefer those specific duplicates to the vague (or as some call them "cannonical") duplicates

Answer (score 4):

The minimum reputation is 1.

You cannot have less than this.

---

For example, a user with reputation 1 posts a question.

That question gets 5 downvotes. The user still has 1 reputation.

The question then gets an upvote. The user will now have 6 reputation.

Comment: yes but will that downvoting affects the user after he had gained enough reputation?

Comment: @Mogana No, there is no "rep debt" to pay off

Answer (score 1):

Reputation cannot go below 1, any loss of reputation below that is simply ignored, as if it never happened (as far as rep is concerned anyway). It can however have other effects; such as being taken into acount for question bans.

As an example

```
Rep change | Current rep | Comment
+0         | 1           |
+5         | 6           |
-2         | 4           |
-2         | 2           |
-2         | 1           |
-2         | 1           |Rep at one, no effect on rep
-2         | 1           |Rep at one, no effect on rep
-2         | 1           |Rep at one, no effect on rep
+5         | 6           |There is no rep debt, the +5 doesn't need to "pay off" the ignored downvotes
```

An example of this can be seen as the first two entries on [your own rep history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/235168/mogana?tab=reputation&sort=time). As you see, you got a downvote then an upvote on this question and yet still have an overall score of 6 because the -2 was ignored when you were at 1 reputation

Comment: what I meant is if five people downvoted that question wat will happen if the user who posted the Question has only 1 reputation?

Comment: Regarding rep, nothing